# Prisma, without @relation?

Tags: prisma

```
model Post{
  //...
  place          Place[]         @relation(fields: [placeId], references: [id])
  placeId         Int
}

model Place{
  //...
  post          Post         @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId        Int
}
```

when I do this,

I got this error

error: Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation field `place` on Model `Post` must not specify the `fields` or `references` argument in the @relation attribute. You must only specif
y it on the opposite field `post` on model `Place`.

how to fix this??

and I don`t understand difference between

just simple post Post (without @relation)

and

post Post @relation(...)

Answer (score 0):

A relation is used to show a connection between two entities or models in the Prisma schema. To fix your issue, you would do something like

```js
model Post{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  place Place[]        
}

model Place{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  post  Post  @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId  Int
}
```

To learn more about relations, please do take a look at the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations)

For an implicit many-to-many relation, you can do

```js
model Post{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  place Place[]        
}

model Place{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  post  Post[]
  postId  Int
}
```

Comment: Hi Raphael, Why Post can not have place Place[] @relation....  ?? I guess I need many to many